# How to connect several html/php files to form a complete website?

Tags: php, sql, html

I've basically made different html files that work with php over wamp server, and I want to know how do I put them together?

For example, I have a login page. I'd like the user to be able to login and see the next html file like a main page or something.

I found the header function in php and I'd also like to know if it's the formal way of redirecting the user from page to page.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do but maybe this could help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: Yes, you can do header.

Comment: oh now I understand. Yeah use header. But you need to set a session in yout html-file too - so make it php

Comment: Basically what you are asking is "How do i build a Website with PHP and MySQL" which is a way to broad question to give an answer to on this platform. Maybe read up on that in a tutorial? Use google for that: https://www.google.de/search?q=build+a+website+with+php+and+mysql

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML Links;

```
<a href="nextpage.html">Next Page</a>
```

You can use Header in PHP files;

```
header("Location:nextpage.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes use header() function of PHP to redirect user to your Home page OR Dashboard page after succeful login of a user:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
```

To add different files into one page,you can use include_once(), require_once(), include(), require() functions as per your requirement.
[Click Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct you are trying to authenticate using a PHP code and based on that redirect the user to the HTML page

You can use the following code

```
    <?php

    if(authneticate();) {

    header("Location: http://www.yoururl.com/home.html");
    exit;

    }
    else {
      header("Location: http://www.yoururl.com/error.html");
    exit;
     }



?>
```

Comment: If the files were local, is it written as for example header("Location: mainpage.html"); ?//given that mainpage.html is also stored in the same file ofcourse